# Slack & Gitlab webhook integration doesn't work

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, slack

I'm trying to integrate Slack with Gitlab. 
I configured everything properly according to 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/project_services/slack.html

In Gitlab, pressing "Test Settings" indeed triggers the webhook and I see the message in my Slack channel.

Also, running 
`$ curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#commits", "username": "webhookbot", "text": "blahblah", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/mywebhookhere`
works perfectly

But when I actually push something into the repository..nothing happens. (Although I can see the commits in the Gitlab UI..)

Any assist would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to enable the **Push** trigger in Gitlab? Check out [this link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/slack.html#gitlab-configuration) for more details.
[image: Gitlab settings]